# Repeat a second If condition using or

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, if-statement

```
main_dict=
{1: {'Origin': '001', 'Destination': '002', 'Cost': '0100.00','Time': '04.00'}, 
 2: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '003', 'Cost': '0500.00', 'Time': '01.50'}, 
 3: {'Origin': '003', 'Destination': '004', 'Cost': '0200.00', 'Time': '11.40'}, 
 4: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '004', 'Cost': '0700.00', 'Time': '10.00'}, 
 5: {'Origin': '004', 'Destination': '006', 'Cost': '0550.00', 'Time': '06.75'}, 
 6: {'Origin': '004', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '0750.00', 'Time': '10.50'}, 
 7: {'Origin': '005', 'Destination': '006', 'Cost': '0460.00', 'Time': '08.00'}, 
 8: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '1500.00', 'Time': '05.75'}}
count=9
first_list=[]                   
second_list=[]
for c in range(1,count):            
    first_list.append(main_dict[c]['Origin'])   #puts all origins in one list
    second_list.append(main_dict[c]['Destination'])#puts all destinations iin one list
locations=[]
locations.extend(first_list)
locations.extend(second_list)
locations=(list(set(locations)))#gets rid of any duplicates
locations.sort()
mat_nxn = [[None for x in range(len(locations))] for y in range(len(locations))] #in this section the main matrix is created 
for i in range(len(locations)):
    mat_nxn[0][i]=locations[i] #fills the first row with the locations
    mat_nxn[i][0]=locations[i] #fills the first column with the locations

for n in range(0,len(locations)-1):
    for i in range(0,len(locations)):
         if str(mat_nxn[0][n])==main_dict[n+1]['Origin'] or str(mat_nxn[i][0])==main_dict[i+1]['Destination'] :
            a=int(mat_nxn[0][n])
            b=int(mat_nxn[n][0])
            mat_nxn[b][a]=main_dict[n+1].values()
```

So what my code is supposed to do is to arrange the dictionary's info in a NxN matrix, how it works is that the "Origin" and "Destination" are the "borders" of the martix

[image]

Then, if let us say I can go from "Origin" to a "Destination" as stated in the SAME dictionary, it will be added it to the matrix under the right (X,Y) of the matrix
an example would be, in the first dictionary I can go from "Origin 001" to "Destination 002" so I will place the values of the dictionary under X,Y(001,002) in the matrix
My problem is in the last part of the code where I used the `if` condition with `or` inside two `for` loops

```
for n in range(0,len(locations)-1):
   for i in range(0,len(locations)):
     if str(mat_nxn[0][n])==main_dict[n+1]['Origin'] or str(mat_nxn[i][0])==main_dict[i+1]['Destination'] :
```

Now the problem is that if I have a duplicate "Origin" *in my case it is 002* it will not check the rest "Destinations", only the first one, and so my output can not be completed. How can I make it check all of them? did I use the `or` the wrong way?
Would appreciate any help

Comment: The outputs has to be an absolute matrix (lists of lists)?, or it could be another structure that mimics it, like a dict of dicts?

Comment: No, a dict of dicts would suit just fine, but keep in mind that if there is no trip from "Origin" to "Destination" the (X,Y) should show None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Enigma: here is a solution with a  dict of dicts as the output:

```
import sys

main_dict = {
    1: {'Origin': '001', 'Destination': '002', 'Cost': '0100.00', 'Time': '04.00'}, 
    2: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '003', 'Cost': '0500.00', 'Time': '01.50'},
    3: {'Origin': '003', 'Destination': '004', 'Cost': '0200.00', 'Time': '11.40'}, 
    4: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '004', 'Cost': '0700.00', 'Time': '10.00'}, 
    5: {'Origin': '004', 'Destination': '006', 'Cost': '0550.00', 'Time': '06.75'}, 
    6: {'Origin': '004', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '0750.00', 'Time': '10.50'}, 
    7: {'Origin': '005', 'Destination': '006', 'Cost': '0460.00', 'Time': '08.00'}, 
    8: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '1500.00', 'Time': '05.75'}
}

locations = {}

origins = set([x['Origin'] for x in main_dict.values()])
destinations = set([x['Destination'] for x in main_dict.values()])

_min = min(origins) if min(origins) < min(destinations) else min(destinations)
_max = max(origins) if max(origins) > max(destinations) else max(destinations)

for origin in origins:
    for destination in destinations:
        if origin not in locations.keys():
            locations[origin] = {}
        if destination not in locations[origin].keys():
            locations[origin][destination] = None

for travel in main_dict.values():
    locations[travel['Origin']][travel['Destination']] = (
        int(travel['Origin']), 
        int(travel['Destination']),
        float(travel['Cost']), 
        float(travel['Time'])
    )
```

A representation of the solution:

```
# ||====================================================================================================================================================================================||
# ||          Data          ||          001           ||          002           ||          003           ||          004           ||          005           ||          006           ||
# ||====================================================================================================================================================================================||
# ||          001           ||          None          ||   (1, 2, 100.0, 4.0)   ||          None          ||          None          ||          None          ||          None          ||
# ||          002           ||          None          ||          None          ||   (2, 3, 500.0, 1.5)   ||  (2, 4, 700.0, 10.0)   ||  (2, 5, 1500.0, 5.75)  ||          None          ||
# ||          003           ||          None          ||          None          ||          None          ||  (3, 4, 200.0, 11.4)   ||          None          ||          None          ||
# ||          004           ||          None          ||          None          ||          None          ||          None          ||  (4, 5, 750.0, 10.5)   ||  (4, 6, 550.0, 6.75)   ||
# ||          005           ||          None          ||          None          ||          None          ||          None          ||          None          ||   (5, 6, 460.0, 8.0)   ||
# ||          006           ||          None          ||          None          ||          None          ||          None          ||          None          ||          None          ||
# ||====================================================================================================================================================================================||
```

The *nasty* code to reproduce that output:

```
def draw():
    _template = '||{: ^24}'
    _range = range(int(_min), int(_max) + 1)
    print("||" + "=" * (26 * (len(_range) + 1) -2) + "||")
    print("||          Data          {}||".format("".join([_template.format(str(x).zfill(3)) for x in _range])))
    print("||" + "=" * (26 * (len(_range) + 1) -2) + "||")
    for origin in _range:
        _origin = str(origin).zfill(3)
        line = _template.format(_origin)    
        for destination in _range:
            #print(_origin, _destination)
            try:
                _destination = str(destination).zfill(3)
                value = locations[_origin][_destination]
                #print(_origin, _destination)
                #print("value",value)
                line += _template.format(str(value))
            except KeyError:
                #print("Error")
                #print(_origin, _destination)
                line += _template.format("None")
        line += '||'
        print(line)
    print("||" + "=" * (26 * (len(_range) + 1) -2) + "||"
```